How can I check all the prime numbers in a for loop?
I want my program to take an integer and put every prime number up to that integer into an ArrayList. Logically I can't find why it doesn't work.
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class primenumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int totalNumber = 1000;
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= totalNumber; i++){
            boolean isPrime = true;

            for(int j = i-1; j >= 1; j--){
                if (i % j == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                }else if(isPrime = true){
                    numbers.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}

What it ends up doing is putting every number up to 1000 repeatedly into the list and printing it out. The nested for loop checks against every number smaller than the original for loop and checks if it has a remainder. I would think that would work as a prime check.

if (isPrime = true) is also separately a bug.  Use == with two equals signs, or better, use if (isPrime).

small note: 1 is not prime by definition (mathematical reason)

You have two bugs. One is testing i % 1 == 0 when j = 1 because your loop test was j >= 1 - should have been j > 1. Second was testing isPrime before your primality test is complete (and with an unfortunate typo }else if(isPrime = true){ assigns true to isPrime and evaluates to true, use if(isPrime) or if(isPrime == true) if you must - it still needs to be tested after you loop through all i % j tests). Fixing that, should look something like
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int totalNumber = 1000;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumber; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int j = i - 1; j > 1; j--) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
}

And I then get
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

Reviewing the code further, we could make a few optimizations; we know that factors of composite numbers must be less than or equal to the square root of the number (because x*x <= y where y is any composite number and x is a factor of y) and we also know that two is the only even prime. Thus we can start at three and increment by two (halving the tests). That leads to something like,
int totalNumber = 1000;
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(2);
outer: for (int i = 3; i <= totalNumber; i += 2) {
    for (int j = (int) Math.sqrt(i); j > 2; j--) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            continue outer; // It isn't prime, skip it
        }
    }
    numbers.add(i);
}
System.out.println(numbers);


alternative for inner loop: j = 3; j*j <= i; j++ (or even j+=2 since only handling odd numbers)

@user85421 You mean j = 3; j*j <= i; j += 2. And yes! :)

@user85421 Very nice.

another optimization would be to test only against the numbers (primes) already on the list (excluding 2)

@user85421 Or just use the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

the program is not effectively checking all the prime numbers in a for loop. Instead, it is creating an ArrayList and repeatedly adding every number up to 1000 to it, regardless of whether the number is prime or not.
To check all the prime numbers in a for loop, you would need to implement a prime number checking algorithm within the loop., you could use the following:

Initialize an ArrayList to store the prime numbers.
Iterate through the numbers from 2 to the desired upper limit (e.g., 1000).
For each number, check if it is prime by testing if it is divisible by any number from 2 up to the square root of the number.
If the number is prime, add it to the ArrayList.
After the loop, the ArrayList will contain all the prime numbers up to the desired upper limit.

Here's an example:
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int upperLimit = 1000;
        ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                primeNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(primeNumbers);
    }
}


BTW there is no need to test if i is divisible by all numbers up to sqrt(i), just if it is divisible by the primes already in primeNumbers
